# windows update error 80244019

Tags: hp-laptop

I am using Windows 10 Pro on a HP Laptop 14S - er003TU. Last night, I tried updating Windows to the latest Windows October update, but I got error code '0x80244019'. This error occurs every time I try to update Windows.

Firstly, I thought this may be occurring due to internet connectivity. I connected my laptop to LAN instead of Wi-Fi, but the problem is still the same. Can anyone help me with this? Waiting for the suggestions.

Comment: Error '0x80244019' occurs when the computer was able to connect to the Windows servers, but was unable to find what was requested.

Answer (score 0):

**Try turning on DEP (Data Execution Prevention). This solution works for most people with this problem:**

- Type 'performance' into the Windows search bar
- Select 'Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows'
- Select the 'Data Execution Prevention (DEP)' tab
- Select 'Turn on DEP for Essential Windows Programs and Services only'
- Click 'OK'
- Restart your computer and check to see if the problem persists

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @rakhigupta223 You can check here: https://community.windows.com/en-us/conversations/windows-7-update-error:-80244019/cae60456-9d1a-438a-b1f5-ef596227225f?from=search